# Turn weak reference to strong

Tags: python, kivy, weak-references, strong-references

In my code label object is weakly referenced. How can I turn it to strongly referenced one? I got the error 'weakly referenced object no longer exists'. Will increasing the references to that object help?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class Audioplayer(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 2 )
        btn = Button(text = "Arey Band kar")
        lbl = Label(text = "gaana ban Raha hai")

        music = SoundLoader.load("prb.mp3")

        if music:
            music.play()

        layout.add_widget(btn)
        layout.add_widget(lbl)

        return layout
        
Audioplayer().run()
```

Comment: What is your development environment: Python version, Kivy version, OS, IDE, etc? Are this error on bouildozer? What are the specs?

Comment: I don't think your Label is weakly referenced, why do you think it is?

Comment: The code runs without any errors on my arch linux system when using kivy-1.11.1 with python-3.8.6.

Comment: I am coding in an Android smartphone in an app named Pydroid3 . Python version 3